Find all the prime number $p$ such that $\dfrac{5^{p-1}-1}{p}$ is perfect square.
Find all the prime number $p$ such that $\dfrac{5^{p-1}-1}{p}$ is perfect square.
With $p=2q+1$, i got $\dfrac{5^{p-1}-1}{p}=\dfrac{(5^q-1)(5^q+1)}{p}$ then $5^q+1$ or $5^q-1$ must be perfect square.
The first case $5^q+1=m^2$, i got $5^q=(m-1)(m+1)$, then $m-1=5^a$ and $m+1=5^b$. It show that $5^b-5^a=2$, so there is no $a$, $b$ for this cases.
With, the second case $5^q-1=m^2$, i got stuck. Is there any hint for that? Thank you for helping me.

Did you mean $5^{p-1}$ rather than $5^p$? If not, your factorisation of the odd-$p$ case makes no sense.

ah sorry, i typed wrong

It's not quite true that one of those factors must be a perfect square.  Their GCD is 2, and if their product is p times a perfect square, then 2 must divide both of them to an odd power.  But any other prime must divide only one of them, and only to an even power.

Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4184457/221315

See AoPS, or this post.

Simple substitution rules out the $p=2$ case. So let $p=2k+1$ for some integer $k\geq 1$ and let $n$ be an integer such that
$$
p\cdot n^2=5^{p-1}-1=(5^k-1)(5^k+1).
$$
Both factors on the RHS are even, so LHS is divisible by $2$. Since $p$ is odd, $n$ must be even, say $n=2m$. Then
$$
p\cdot m^2=\frac{5^k-1}{2}\cdot\frac{5^k+1}{2}.
$$
Since $\gcd(5^k-1,5^k+1)=2$, both factors on the RHS are coprime. Thus exactly only one of the two is divisible by $p$, and after division the remaining factors must be perfect squares. In particular, we have either $5^k-1=2u^2$ or $5^k+1=2u^2$. Reducing $\bmod 5$ the first equality gives $4\equiv 2u^2\pmod 5$, but $2u^2\equiv 0,2,3\pmod 5$, impossible. Similarly, the second equality gives $1\equiv 2u^2\pmod 5$, again impossible.
Hence there is no integer solution.
